# ASP - custom route

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I define a new route in my asp.net project

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}.{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and controller (lets call it TempController) that have 2 actions :

1. Index that does not get any argument
2. CheckParameter that have one argument - input (string)

How to create a route to TempController to action CheckParameter?

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: which version of aspnet mvc are you using? mvc 5 or mvc 6. I am guessing this for a controller not a Web Api

Comment: mvc 5 and its not web api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home Route For Temp:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "TempHome",
        url: "{controller}.{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Temp", action = "Index"}
    );
```

Check Route For Temp:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "TempCheck",
        url: "{controller}.{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Temp", action = "CheckParameter", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

usage: http://www.website.com/temp.checkparameter/id

or you can have this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "TempCheck",
        url: "CheckSomething/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Temp", action = "CheckParameter", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

usage for id=10: 
http://www.website.com/CheckSomething/10

Comment: Can you give me an example how to go to TempControler to CheckParameter action (url )?

Answer (score 0):

New Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "TempCheck",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{stringParam}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Temp", action="CheckParameter",stringParam= UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

TempController.cs

```
public ActionResult CheckParameter(string stringParam){

}
```

Invocation

```
localhost:9090/temp/CheckParameter/PassAnyString
```

If you do not wish to add a new route you can also try this

```
http://localhost:9090/temp/CheckParameter?stringParam=11
In a @Url.Action would be :

@Url.Action("CheckParameter","temp", new {stringParam=11});
```

Comment: I really want create my custom route with . not with /

Comment: try the above approach by replacing / with a . after controller I think that should work as well